# Way to force download with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets, dojo

I need a way to 'force' the download of a file when the AJAX response of a Post is returned.

I can't use `window.open()` because I don't have an useful URL.

Is there any way using Javascript or Dojo toolkit to force the download of the file inside of the HTTP Response?

Comment: No. Return the file with `application/octet-stream` mime type and the save-as will popup

Comment: The server tells it to force download using application/octet-stream. Some browsers prefer to display certain files inline, like Chrome and PDFs. You might have to add an outbound rule on your server to override that.

Comment: sure, just use ajax instead of a form to get the response as a string. then just download the string. http://danml.com/js/download.js will let you save a string as a file. you can also actually use a popup (like window.open) by simply giving the form a target="_blank"

Answer (score 0):

Your server needs to add the Content-Type and Content-Disposition headers to force a download.

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.ext
```